# How can I re-use a session cookie between terminations (Android)

Tags: php, javascript, android

I want to create a session on a server backend for Joomla PHP and a Javascript quiz module, that are used from an Android application.

Even if the Android application closes unexpectedly, that session should be available again on a subsequent load of the application.

What's the best way someone can suggest for this?

Comment: php sessions use the `PHPSESSID` cookies. just store them on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest storing the PHP Session cookies on disk if you are going to use `$_SESSION` in PHP. Otherwise, you should look into [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) that you can manually set the expiry time on and keep them stored on disk in `Cache/`

That will store the current progress of the application in the session cookie, but without a login (or code from you) there's not that much more i can say. 
To access from another browser/device you would need a login to identify the user and provide them with a valid session.

Comment: I need to access quiz at same state. but its loading stating state when load page.. I want php page that can be accessed by multiple users or devices with some unique id at same state

Comment: pardon? you can store progress on disk. disk is your non-volatile (safe) storage that persists between closes.

Comment: yep I can create user credentials and login sessions but. I am not getting exact idea to access same quiz at same state with that user details and sessions

Comment: the state can only be give to the same person without fail using sessions + logins. there's no other way to do it, or you risk giving a session from someone else to the wrong person. the idea is that you store the state inside of this.

Comment: quiz start with some random questions and runs with some time. but how access that same quiz at same state on another browser of device

Comment: actually I wanted to do android application which load that php quiz page and runs as application.. so I wanted to make a session on server side with some unique id and access that quiz at different times also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23736/discussion-between-chandan-pasunoori-and-hiroto)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a user account in your database for each phone, maybe identified by the phone's udid.
2. Store the data in your database as the user moves through the quiz
3. When the user opens the app, check their udid against your database and retrieve any data that is needed for that user

Comment: can you explain me.. that php quiz module in joomla run like one question after another.. with some javascript and ajax code internally. then how to hold same page at different time